# Optimizing git multi-merge to master

Tags: git, commit, git-commit

Given a collection of hashes for branch tips, is it possible to construct a tree of some sort to determine which tips are candidates for merging and which ones aren't with the current master of a project?

I'm not a CI/CD guy, but I'm trying to understand from a physics for poets standpoint if it's possible to construct a tree of some sort to determine which branches are eligible to be merged to master and which ones aren't.

### Clarification

For the purposes of this query, the collection of branch tips in question are branches that 1) have no conflicts with master and 2) have passed all CI tests.

Comment: There are different questions to ask here. The only one Git can answer on its own is: *I can/cannot merge this on my own, without help to fix conflicts.* That's probably not a particularly good question to answer, though.

Comment: Define "eligible" and "candidates for merging". For example, does it refer to branches that don't have conflicts? (Though, depending on the situation, some feature branches need to be merged even if they have conflicts.) Or does it refer to branches where the CI tests passed? For that you need to setup CI configuration that runs on merge requests, and marks/flags those branches where the tests fail.

Comment: @GinoMempin I updated my question with clarification.

Answer (score 1):

What it sounds like you want is some sort of way to test mergeability.  In general, this is hard with the command-line Git binary.  You can attempt a test merge and run `git merge --abort` if it exits non-zero, but you are better off using libgit2 (or a wrapper in your preferred language) for this purpose, which provides the `GIT_MERGE_FAIL_ON_CONFLICT` flag which can be used to detect this case without modifying the repository.

As for checking with your CI or CD system to see if all the tests have passed, presumably it is possible.  You haven't told us what system you're using, but many such systems have an API that you can use.

If you're using a Git hosting platform such as GitHub, you can query it for that state instead so you don't have to do it yourself.  GitHub has documentation on how to [check if a pull request is mergeable](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/#checking-mergeability-of-pull-requests), and there's also a checks API you can use.